# Core data relationship lost after editing nested object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an entity named `Geometry` which is related to a `Plot` entity. In our piece of code, given the `Plot` and some downloaded data stored in a `NSDictionary`, we must get the `Geometry` and set some `NSString` properties but, after doing that, I find that the relationship between entities is lost.

```
NSError * saveError = nil;

NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:[Geometry entityName]];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"plot == %@", plot];
NSError * error = nil;
NSArray * results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

Geometry * __block geometry = nil;

if ([results count] > 0) {
    [results enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * stop) {
        Geometry * geometryObject = obj;
        if ([geometryObject.gid isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [data valueForKey:@"gid"]]]) {
            geometry = geometryObject;
            stop = YES;
        }
    }];
}

if (geometry != nil) {
    [geometry setPolygon:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [data valueForKey:@"polygon"]]];
}

if (![context save:&saveError]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", saveError);
}
```

The first time I run this code `results` have one object, but the next time I run this there is no `results`.

<del>Assume everything outside the scope of this piece of code is working right.</del> Any hint or clue about why this happen? How can I solve this?

**EDIT**: The problem has been solved outside the scope of the code posted and outside the scope of this question. I should have properly reviewed the code further.

Comment: Why do you enumerate through the results instead of modifying the predicate to return the single `Geometry` object in the first place?

Comment: @Avi If there are more than one result, they are processed outside the scope of this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in your code that breaks the relationship. The error must be elsewhere.

You have a `Plot` object, so you can get the geometries with `plot.geometries` without a fetch request, and filter them without a loop:

```
Geometry *geometry = [plot.geometries
   filteredArrayUsingPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"gid = %@", gidString]]
   .firstObject
```

where `geometries` is the name of the inverse relationship for `plot`.

You can now set the `polygon` property and save. Check your `setPolygon` method if you are not removing the relationship.

Comment: Thanks for responding, @Mundi. Unfortunately the problem has been solved by another way. Remember the quote `Assume everything outside the scope of this piece of code is working right` in my question? Please, don't assume that, I shouldn't. Upvoted because it helped to improve my code.

Comment: I updated the answer so you can accept it and close this issue.